# Problemas para aplicar una función de normalización

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, pandas

Aquí una muy pequeña vista de las variables de una base de datos que estoy ocupando para un ejercicio sobre clasificación.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 41188 entries, 0 to 41187
Data columns (total 21 columns):
age               41188 non-null int64
job               41188 non-null object
marital           41188 non-null object

dtypes: float64(5), int64(6), object(10)
memory usage: 6.6+ MB
```

Quiero normalizar la variable `age` y para eso cree una función sencilla:

```
def normalize(X):
    NORM = []
    for i in X:
        norm= (i-min(X))/(max(X)-min(X))
        NORM.append(norm)
    return NORM
```

El problema es que cuando la intento aplicar con `map` o con `apply` para crear una nueva variable obtengo el mismo error:

```
log["age_n"]=  log["age"].apply(normalize)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

log["age_n"]=  log["age"].map(normalize)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Cualquier orientación sobre este error la apreciaré muchísimo.

Comment: ¿`X` se supone que es la columna "age" e `i` cada una de sus filas?  Ten en cuenta que `apply` pasa cada fila a la función, no la columna entera.

Comment: En efecto, X es "age" e "i" las observaciones. ¿Cuál sería la forma correcta entonces? Estoy intentando con log["age_n"]= normalize(log["age"]) aunque mi computadora va un poco lenta...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply` pasa a la función cada fila y la función retorna el valor correspondiente para esa misma fila. Al recibir el valor de cada fila de la columna `age`, un entero, obtienes el error mostrado al intentar iterar sobre el con `for i in X`, ya que `X` es cada observación y no la columna completa.

La función debería ser por tanto algo así:

```
min_age = log["age"].min()
dif_age = log["age"].max() - min_age

def normalize(row):
    return(row - min_age) / dif_age

log["age_n"] = log["age"].apply(normalize)
```

O usar una función anónima:

```
min_age = log["age"].min()
dif_age = log["age"].max() - min_age
log["age_n"] = log["age"].apply(lambda row: (row - min_age) / dif_age)
```

No obstante, **para lo que quieres hacer no necesitas (ni debes) usar `apply`**, existe una forma más simple y eficiente aprovechando la vectorización ofrecida por Pandas/NumPy sin tener que recurrir a una función Python.

Partiendo de un ejemplo reproducible:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> data = {"age":     [20,  34,  82,  47,  95,  14,  58], 
            "job":     ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"], 
            "marital": ["b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"]}

>>> log = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Podemos obtener la nueva columna simplemente con:

```
>>> min_age = log["age"].min()
>>> dif_age = log["age"].max() - min_age
>>> log["age_n"] = (log["age"] - min_age) / dif_age
>>> log

   age job marital     age_n
0   20   a       b  0.074074
1   34   a       b  0.246914
2   82   a       b  0.839506
3   47   a       b  0.407407
4   95   a       b  1.000000
5   14   a       b  0.000000
6   58   a       b  0.543210
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. ¡Muchas gracias!